# Adding an event handler to a pure React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components, react-redux

I have a React component with a Redux container on top of it that I want to handle scroll events on:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Visualization extends React.Component {
    render() {
        function handleScroll(e) {
            if (e.deltaY > 0) {
                console.log("YO");
                this.props.stepForward();  // stepForward inherited from above
            } else {
                console.log("DAWG");
                this.props.stepBack();  // stepBack inherited from above
            }
        }

        return <div onWheel={handleScroll}>"HELLO WORLD"</div>;
    }
}
```

This code will raise an error, however, because `this` is not bound to anything when `this.props.stepForward()` finally gets called as part of the event.

The React tutorial [handles this case](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) by adding a constructor and calling `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);` within it. Or, equivalently:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Visualization extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        function handleScroll(e) {
            if (e.deltaY > 0) {
                console.log("YO");
                this.props.stepForward();  // stepForward inherited from above
            } else {
                console.log("DAWG");
                this.props.stepBack();  // stepBack inherited from above
            }
        }

        return <div onWheel={handleScroll}>"HELLO WORLD"</div>;
    }
}
```

But as I understand it (tell me if I'm wrong), this is no longer a purely functional component, and Redux really wants me to be using pure components whenever possible.

Is there a pattern for adding this event handler to my component without having to resort to an explicit constructor?

Comment: It wasn't stateless from the start since you extended React.Component, which gives you the lifecycle methods. If you want a pure, stateless component, it's just const `SomeComponent = (props) => <span>{props.stuff}<span>)`

Comment: I see. I've misremembered the format for a [functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#functional-components) then, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need handlers for DOM events, your component is probably too complicated to be a pure component. No component **has** to be a pure component (for React, Redux, or any related library), it's just ideal because they tend to be simpler and will have performance benefits in future React releases. To fix this component, change it to this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Visualization extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    }

    handleScroll(e) {
        if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            console.log("YO");
            this.props.stepForward();  // stepForward inherited from above
        } else {
            console.log("DAWG");
            this.props.stepBack();  // stepBack inherited from above
        }
    }

    render() {   
        return <div onWheel={handleScroll}>"HELLO WORLD"</div>;
    }
}
```

P.S. If you want this component to be pure, extend your class from `React.PureComponent`, not `React.Component`. Alternatively, you can make your component a function instead of a class.